# Python 2D List Conditional Mapping from Multiple 2D Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array, coordinates

I have a list of lists A that looks like this

```py
A = [[1, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [0, 1, 0]]
```

Then I have two other list of lists B and C that looks as below:

```py
B = [['a', 'c', 's'],
     ['y', 'e', 's'],
     ['u', 'w', 'g']]

C = [['i', 'p', 'u'],
     ['k', 'l', 'n'],
     ['h', 'o', 'm']]
```

I am trying to perform mapping from A to B and C, with value conditioning:

When the 'cell' value is 1, refer to the value at the same position in B, and likewise refer to C when it is 0.

I tried to break down the problem by trying to map list to lists. But it seems to lead to nowhere.

How can I map A to B and C so that it results in a list of lists like this?

```py
[['a', 'p', 'u'],   # 'a' from B; 'p' from C; 'u' from C
 ['y', 'e', 's'],   # 'y' from B; 'e' from B; 's' from B
 ['h', 'w', 'm']]   # 'h' from C; 'w' from B; 'm' from C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the 3 lists together by zipping them first:

```
[[a and b or c for a, b, c in zip(*t)] for t in zip(A, B, C)]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/f8XRdk

Answer (score 1):

```
def exchange(value_map, zipped_list):
    temp = []
    for i, row in enumerate(value_map):
        temp_inner = []
        for j, obj in enumerate(row):
            temp_inner.append(zipped_list[obj][i][j])
        temp.append(temp_inner)
    return temp


print(exchange(A, [C, B]))
```

I made it as function.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I found a way using `np.ndenumerate`:-

```py
import numpy as np

for (x,y), e in np.ndenumerate(A):
    if e == 1: # or any or more conditions
        A[x][y] = B[x][y]
    else:
        A[x][y] = C[x][y]
```

The accepted answer above is best for two conditionings (1/0).